# Bootstrap typeahead store more values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a bsic typeahead setup, where I search for cities names, but onselect I also need the lat and long for that city so I can send it to the backend.

```
  $('.typeahead').typeahead({
    minLength : 3,
    source : function(typeahead,query){
        return $.ajax({
        url: appUrl+"/"+query,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
          var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
          var locations = [];
          $(data).each(function(index,value){
            locations.push(value.City);
          });
          return typeahead.process(locations);
        }
      });
    },
    onselect : function(item){

      console.log(item);
    }
  });
```

So I'm receiving from the JSon the lat and long but I don't know how to store them in the source array, so I can use them on the onselect action, any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create another object where to store the data, so I can access it later.

```
 var locationsData = {};
  $('.typeahead').typeahead({
    minLength : 3,
    source : function(typeahead,query){
        return $.ajax({
        url: appUrl+"/"+query,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
          var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
          var locations = [];
          $(data).each(function(index,value){
            locations.push(value.City);
            locationsData[value.City] = {'Lat' : value.Latitude, 'Long' : value.Longitude};
          });
          return typeahead.process(locations);
        }
      });
    },
    onselect : function(item){

      console.log(item);
      console.log(locationsData);
      console.log(locationsData[item].Lat);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Your solution definitely works but I would more elegantly overrides twitter typeahead functions : matcher, sorter, updater & highlighter. More code :( but I would be able to write "return typeahead.process($data)" and not need to create unnecessary arrays.